# Many to Many with eager loading in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this model:

```
class Ownership extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'game_user';

    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
    }

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('owntype');
    }
}
```

Models for `Game` and `Owntype` are simple `...extends Eloquent`. This is how I pull the data:

```
$games = Ownership::with('games','type')->where('user_id','=','1')->get();
```

Theoretically, it works. Practically, not, because it returns empty `games` and `owntype` collections. Here's what it returns: http://paste.laravel.com/s94

How can I get `games` and `users` table contents? I don't want to `Game::find` in foreach, because it would produce a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array inside `with()`.
I.e.

```
$games = Ownership::with(array('games','type'))->where('user_id','=','1')->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't change a thing. Laravel 4 accepts both ways of passing `with`. It still doesn't provide data from tables.